# Moment.js show diff between 2 dates

Tags: momentjs

I use `moment(d, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();` to get diff between date now and some date, but I would like to get without string "**a few days ago**".

Instead, I would like to get "**7d**" (7m, 1s, etc).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 45):

If you want just to get the difference between two dates instead of a relative string just use the [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) function.

```js
var date  = moment("20170101", "YYYYMMDD");
var date7 = moment("20170108", "YYYYMMDD");
var mins7 = moment("20170101 00:07", "YYYYMMDD HH:mm");
var secs1 = moment("20170101 00:00:01", "YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss");

console.log(date7.diff(date, "days")    + "d"); // "7d"
console.log(mins7.diff(date, "minutes") + "m"); // "7m"
console.log(secs1.diff(date, "seconds") + "s"); // "1s"
```

Answer (score 18):

[Moment.diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) does exactly that.

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b) // 86400000
```

You can specify a unit:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

Comment: Beautiful. If you read `.diff(` as a minus sign `-`, you also know whether a negative or a positive number comes out.

Answer (score 11):

```js
var before = moment('2017.02.12 09:00','YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm');
var now = moment();

console.log(
  moment(now - before)
  .format('D[ day(s)] H[ hour(s)] m[ minute(s)] s[ second(s) ago.]')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Watch out! This solution is wrong. The result overflows every month.