# Moment js - displaying days and hours away from a date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am working on a project that requires this kind of text response on a date object.

"1 day 7 hours away"
--- it needs to be this way - not "31 hours away" or "1 day away"
-- also I am using moment js - as I am doing language switching between English and German - so I've tapped into the moment.js language locale

```
moment.locale('de')
```

I am using moment js - currently I've created a fake date object

```
  var futureDate = new Date()
  futureDate.setDate(futureDate.getDate() + 1)// add a day
  futureDate.setHours(7)// add 7 hours
```

when I try and render the moment js

```
moment(futureDate).endOf('day').fromNow()
```

it just says "in a day"

How do I modify the moment function to handle 1 day 7 hours -- and maybe re-jig the sentence?

--- code snippet attempt

```js
moment.locale('de') // switch between en and de -- english and german

var futureDate = new Date()
futureDate.setDate(futureDate.getDate() + 1)// add a day
futureDate.setHours(7)// add 4 hours

// Results in hours
console.log(moment(futureDate).endOf('day').fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

code test 2 using difference

```js
moment.locale('de') // switch between en and de -- english and german

var a = moment();
var b = moment(a).add(31, 'hours');

// Results in days
console.log(b.diff(a, 'days'));
console.log(b.diff(a, 'days', true));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, you need to know the time exact 7 hours after?

Comment: Seems to be what you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508796/moment-js-how-to-use-fromnow-to-return-everything-in-hours

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js how to use fromNow() to return everything in hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508796/moment-js-how-to-use-fromnow-to-return-everything-in-hours)

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/

Comment: -- no those are not duplicates -- I need it broken down 1 day 7 hours away -- 31 hours etc..

Comment: ... It is just a very simple conversion from hours to days. Even weeks and months if needed.
That issue looks solved to me.

Comment: Do the math yourself if method doesn't return format you want

Comment: but moment has handling capabilities for this - also needs to do language switch between English and German - and I've got the locale set on moment

Comment: @charlietfl -- what's the point of using moment if its total bespoke handling - and then I still got to do locale considerations for a language switch.

Comment: When you get these "31 hours", you can use the durations in momentjs. ;)
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: @LouisLecocq - error -- moment(futureDate).duration(1, 'hours').endOf('day').fromNow() --- duration not a function

Comment: @TheOldCounty the Durations page also states `It is much better to use moment#diff for calculating days or years between two moments than to use Durations.`

Comment: Sorry. I gave you an answer. I even indicate you the #durations feature of moment.js. Take your time. Read it carefully. Good luck

Comment: Well your suggestion created an error - but not an answer was provided to resolve the problem

Comment: Your suggestion also has left a decimal in days

Comment: I've updated my answer below @TheOldCounty. Also, there's no need for snarkiness towards people trying to help you (e.g. Louis) :)

Comment: I'm not being snarky - but factual - is it ok for him to provide a suggestion, claiming it as an answer then wishing me - "good luck"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`relativeTimeThreshold`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) and [`relativeTime`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) (key of `moment.updateLocale`) to customize how moment shows relative time (e.g. the `fromNow()` output).

In your case, you can:

- Adjust threshold to get difference in seconds (see: [How to make moment.js show relative time in seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42216583/4131048)).
- Create a duration object using [`moment.duration(Number, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/).
- Use [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in to show duration value in the format you prefer.

Here a live sample:

```js
var momEn = moment().add({d:1, h:7});
var momDe = moment().locale('de').add({d:1, h:7});

console.log(momEn.fromNow()); // in a day
console.log(momDe.fromNow()); // in einem Tag

// Change relativeTimeThreshold
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('s', 60*60*24*30*12);

// Update relative time
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  relativeTime : {
    s: function (number, withoutSuffix, key, isFuture){
      return moment.duration(number, 's').format('d [day] h [hour]');
    },
  }
});

moment.updateLocale('de', {
  relativeTime : {
    s: function (number, withoutSuffix, key, isFuture){
      return moment.duration(number, 's').format('d [Tag] h [Uhr]');
    },
  }
});

console.log(momEn.fromNow()); // in 1 day 7 hour
console.log(momDe.fromNow()); // in 1 Tag 7 Uhr
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately you have to manually update each locale you need to support.

Comment: ok - so -- you first convert the time into seconds? -- then use this to format the date moment.duration(number, 's').format('d [day] h [hour]')

Comment: yes. the first step I used is to adjust `relativeTimeThreshold` to get time difference in seconds in the `relativeTime` section, then I created a duration and formatted it using moment-duration-format. Moment relative time functions show give output for a single unit, the solution given in my answer is a sort of workaround.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Since you mentioned you'd like to stick with Moment.js, they have [`moment#diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) available:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

Found from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42187373/2803743

---

I'd use [countdown.js](https://github.com/mckamey/countdownjs) for this.

```
var futureDate = new Date()
futureDate.setDate(futureDate.getDate() + 1)// add a day
futureDate.setHours(7)// add 7 hours
var timePassed = countdown(Date.now().toString(), futureDate, countdown.DAYS|countdown.HOURS);

console.log(timePassed);
```

`timePassed` is a lovely object; in this example:

```
  days: 0
  end: Tue Jul 04 2017 07:17:41 GMT+0300 (EEST)
  hours: 12
  start: Mon Jul 03 2017 19:17:41 GMT+0300 (EEST)
  units: 18
  value: 43200000
```

Which you can then concat to your desired string.

It's not really documented well, but the lib also has a CDN
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/countdown

Comment: and the language handling for countdown? I already got momentjs used on another module - not sure it would be welcome shoveling in another date handling tool - still can't handle the language switching

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on `language handling`? What do you mean by this? Do you need translation/localization capabilities?

Comment: @TheOldCounty Edited my answer to show you usage of Moment's Difference module.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) or with [moment.diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations) like so:

```js
let futureDate = new Date ()
futureDate.setDate (futureDate.getDate () + 1)// add a day
futureDate.setHours (7)
let start = moment ()
let end = moment (futureDate)

// 1st solution: with moment-duration-format

console.log (moment.duration (end.diff (start)).format ('d [days] hh [hours]', { trim: false }))

// 2nd solution: diff without moment-duration-format

let hoursDuration = end.diff (start, 'hours')
console.log (Math.floor (hoursDuration / 24) + ' days ' + (hoursDuration % 24) + ' hours')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

The first solution requires the additional moment-duration-format module, whereas the second does everything using moment.js only. Also, don't forget to `npm install moment-duration-format` before requiring it.

Comment: also how will this work with the language switch -- I was dipping into moment.locale('de')

Comment: @TheOldCounty, I edited the answer and converted it to a code snippet. Also, if you are concerned of locales, there's a locale-supporting version of moment.js at https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js

Comment: but the momentjs that is already installed is working with moment.local -- but you example you've hardcoded English -- days in your console