# How to calculate between dates in Laravel + Vue js project

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, momentjs

I am tired to calculate date with start & end date in my Laravel & Vue js project?
I have also installed moment js. 
Code as below,

> {{item.start_date | MyDate}}
>   {{item.end_date | MyDate}}
>   {{Here will be calculate between above dates}}

Please help me.

Comment: What does the MyDate function do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the data from **Laravel** you can use Carbon to calculate the difference like this:

```
$start_date = Carbon::parse($item->start_date);
$end_date = Carbon::parse($item->end_date);

$diff_in_hours = $end_date->diffInHours($start_date);
$diff_in_days = $end_date->diffInDays($start_date)
$diff_in_minutes = $end_date->diffInMinutes($start_date);
$diff_in_seconds = $end_date->diffInSeconds($start_date);
```

So if you are getting the data from a query you can map the query like this:

```
$schedules = DB::table('schedules')
                 ->get()
                 ->map(function($item){
                     $start_date = Carbon::parse($item->start_date);
                     $end_date = Carbon::parse($item->end_date);
                     $item->diff = $end_date->diffInMinutes($start_date);

                    return $item;
                 });
```

The same for models

```
Schedule::where('status',1)->get()
                 ->map(function($item){
                     $start_date = Carbon::parse($item->start_date);
                     $end_date = Carbon::parse($item->end_date);
                     $item->diff = $end_date->diffInMinutes($start_date);

                    return $item;
                 });
```

Comment: This is on only for Laravel.
Thanks for yours reply.

Answer (score 4):

You can create new method with this logic:

```
methods: {
    parseDate (start, end) {
        return moment(start, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm').diff(moment(end, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm'), "days")
    }
}
```

And in your template you can simply do  that: `{{ parseDate(item.start_date, item.end_date) }}`

I think is that what you need. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186717/moment-js-show-diff-between-2-dates/42187373) you can check some examples of using `diff` in moment.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I am success with you.